# Between math stack exchange and mathoverflow

Tags: discussion, math-stackexchange

Suppose that I posted a question on mathstack exchange and no one has answered it. In my opinion it is not enough reason to post it on mathoverflow but if I also awarded a bounty and still didn't get an answer is it okay to post it on mathoverflow, even it is not quite research level question? (but is more advanced than the standard undergraduate course level).

Comment: This depends on the question. -- The criterion is not whether your question is difficult, but whether it is interesting for the audience on MathOverflow.

Comment: Ok, let me just say, that this is some sort of the question being a folklore, for which everybody says "trivial", but hardly nobody ever done the precise computations rigorously and these can be quite complicated.

Comment: It's perhaps reasonable, if written well with background explanation etc and why such a thing is good to know, to ask it under the [reference-request] tag.

Comment: In my personal experience questions have been well received on MO that didn't get an answer or other helpful response on SE.